# Problem launching Rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

Just started up in Rails. I'm on windows vista, installed the latest build of ruby from http://rubyinstaller.org/ and everything went well.

```
ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09) [i386-mingw32]
```

I run:

```
gem update --system
gem sources -a http://gemcutter.org
gem install rails
```

No errors reported.

```
rails --v
Rails 3.1.0
```

after this I created a folder for my Rails project and I created a new Rails app inside  as follows:

```
rails new test
cd test
bundle install
```

(again no error reported)

But when I run `rails server` I get this error:

```
rails server
←[31mCould not find rails-3.1.0 in any of the sources←[
←[33mRun `bundle install` to install missing gems.←[0m
```

I try to run bundle again but no success again... After this, if I type again rails -v I get the same error as before. I have to close the windows console and reopen for rails -v to start working again!!

Has anyone experience this?! Can you help?

Thanks!!!

As requested the gemfile content is:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.1.0'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails',     :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', "  ~> 3.1.0"
  gem 'coffee-rails', "~> 3.1.0"
  gem 'uglifier'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# Use unicorn as the web server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'

group :test do
  # Pretty printed test output
  gem 'turn', :require => false
end
```

bundle install result:

```
Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
Using rake (0.9.2)
Using multi_json (1.0.3)
Using activesupport (3.1.0)
Using bcrypt-ruby (3.0.0)
Using builder (3.0.0)
Using i18n (0.6.0)
Using activemodel (3.1.0)
Using erubis (2.7.0)
Using rack (1.3.2)
Using rack-cache (1.0.3)
Using rack-mount (0.8.3)
Using rack-test (0.6.1)
Using hike (1.2.1)
Using tilt (1.3.3)
Using sprockets (2.0.0)
Using actionpack (3.1.0)
Using mime-types (1.16)
Using polyglot (0.3.2)
Using treetop (1.4.10)
Using mail (2.3.0)
Using actionmailer (3.1.0)
Using arel (2.2.1)
Using tzinfo (0.3.29)
Using activerecord (3.1.0)
Using activeresource (3.1.0)
Using ansi (1.3.0)
Using bundler (1.0.18)
Using coffee-script-source (1.1.2)
Using execjs (1.2.4)
Using coffee-script (2.2.0)
Using rack-ssl (1.3.2)
Using rdoc (3.9.4)
Using thor (0.14.6)
Using railties (3.1.0)
Using coffee-rails (3.1.0)
Using jquery-rails (1.0.13)
Installing rails (3.1.0)
Using sass (3.1.7)
Using sass-rails (3.1.0)
Using sqlite3 (1.3.4)
Using turn (0.8.2)
Using uglifier (1.0.2)
Your bundle is complete! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem
is installed.
```

Comment: What does your Gemfile look like? What is the output from bundler? Are you using RVM?

Comment: Thanks for the reply!! Regarding the RVM i'm affraid I don't know what it is... Read a bit now but either it was installed automaticly or I don't have it... The other info requested is in the original post!

Comment: RVM is for linux/mac/*nix in general, unless you're using cygwin,  which I doubt, since you installed ruby & rails from http://rubyinstaller.org.

Comment: how could you create an application called `test`? It gives me an error both on windows an linux with the message **Invalid application name test. Please give a name which does not match one of the reserved rails words.**

Comment: it's called hello actually. sorry for the mistake

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try `bundle exec rails server` instead of `rails server`

Comment: I tried it but got this message this time: "Could not find rails-3.1.0 in any of the sources"

Comment: Make sure you don't have `rails` in your `vendor` directory

Comment: i'm sorry but what do you mean by vendor?

Comment: normally, there's a `vendor` directly in your app's root, alongside `app`, `config`, `lib`, etc...

Comment: Try running `bundle check` and `bundle list` to see if any errors show up

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3113/discussion-between-john-douthat-and-jribeiro)